# Python / matplotlib graphics & OS X 10.9: mission control?

Tags: mission-control, python

I just got set up on OS X 10.9, and I have matplotlib working with the OS X backend, but the "python" window that shows up is partially inaccessible to Mission Control.

If I activate full Mission Control with F12 (your shortcut key may vary), it appears with the name "python".

However, there is no python icon in the Dock, and ⌘- doesn't show any icon.

Is there any way to get the python app to appear in the dock?

Comment: How did you install matplotlib?

Comment: `pip install matplotlib` or `/usr/local/bin/pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Actually, I used `conda` for this version (https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem using Anaconda Python. The problem seems to be related to the fact that Anaconda is not a "framework" installation. For more information, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130355/python-matplotlib-framework-under-macosx

and

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/665#issuecomment-11327805

With Anaconda installed, my default `python` executable is Anaconda's:

```
$ which python
/Users/dgolden/anaconda/bin/python
```

A solution that works for me is to explicitly call the system python installation, which is installed in `/usr/bin/python` for me, e.g.,

```
/usr/bin/python /path/to/my/script.py
```

You can save yourself some typing by creating a symlink with a unique name that won't be shadowed by anaconda (the `fw` suffix that I use suggests "framework"):

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /usr/bin/pythonfw
```

Then you can run your script with:

```
pythonfw /path/to/my/script.py
```

Comment: The general comment seems reasonable buut the workarounds do not seem good to me - what happens if the python in Anaconda is a different version to the system one? Also just put `#!/bin/python` as the first line of a script. That python is already linked to /usr/bin/python

Comment: I think it's just not possible to get the matplotlib window behavior correct with Anaconda. So regardless of whether the versions are different, you have to use the system one. But you are right, `/usr/bin/python` does seem to work for me.

Comment: If it works then it is luck - Anaconda version does not necessarily mach system version (and almost certainly has a difference in minor version) Don't mix versions. Better to install a python.org - or inn this case macports or home-brew python, the latter give matplotlib as well and are framework versions